# Sometimes can't establish connection to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, firewall

We have an application in Microsoft Access 2000 (sorry, can't help it), connected to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and it doesn't have any connection issues. Our application uses a .NET ActiveX control, which has to connect to that same SQL Server. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't, I'm getting the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26: - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

It seems to be firewall related. When I turn off the Windows Firewall on the server where SQL Server is running, only for the "Domain network settings", and turn it immediately on again, the issue is solved for some time (a couple of hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the system admin has found the answer. He checked the firewall log files and found out that port number 1434 was blocked for the UDP protocol, so he had to open it in the firewall settings.

> Port 1434 is used by the SQL Browser Service which allows connections to named instances of SQL Server that use dynamic ports with out having to know what port each named instance is using, especially since this can change between restarts of the named instance. [[link]](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1341423.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're working from home (e.g. Local Windows 7, 8.1, 10 computer), and trying to connect to a remote database (via SQL Server Database Engine, Using SSMS) the following is most likely what you want...

Go to Windows Firewall:
First, create a new **OUTBOUND** Rule, select "port", and "allow" TCP Port 1433.
Then, create a new **OUTBOUND** Rule, select "port", and "allow" UDP Port 1434.
Lastly, find the path to your SSMS.  (E.g. right click the SSMS shortcut, go to properties, find the "target" path, and copy it.
Then, create a new OUTBOUND Rule, select program, paste in the path you copied, and allow it.

That's it.

Note: If you're actually on a physical server, or a virtual machine that's hosting the database, you should follow the same steps, but create INBOUND Rules instead.

Hope this helps, it helped me.  :-)